# Different types of arrays in a common block in FORTRAN77

Tags: fortran, precision

I need double precision for some arrays (not all) of a common block which is used by 4 subroutines. The problem is that by changing the common block from the form A to B, my code blows up after a few iterations.

A)

```
  COMMON/MYBK/
   C0(I,J,K),C1(I,J,K),C2(I,J,K),
 & C3(I,J,K),C4(I,J,K),C5(I,J,K),
 & CD0(I,J,K),CD1(I,J,K),CD2(I,J,K),
 & CD3(I,J,K),CD4(I,J,K),CD5(I,J,K)
```

B)

```
  DOUBLE PRECISION
 & C0(I,J,K),C1(I,J,K),C2(I,J,K) 
  COMMON/MYBK/
   C0,C1,C2,
 & C3(I,J,K),C4(I,J,K),C5(I,J,K),
 & CD0(I,J,K),CD1(I,J,K),CD2(I,J,K),
 & CD3(I,J,K),CD4(I,J,K),CD5(I,J,K)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you change the type of  `C0,C1,C2` before every occurence of that common block?

Comment: what is the type of `C0`, `C1`, and `C2` in the first common block?

Comment: @Andras Deak, yes I did.

Comment: @casey, in all four occurrences are the same as the form B, which does not work.

Comment: bloodybutunbowed0, I think @casey meant to know what the type was in case A.

Comment: Also: are you sure that it's the common block that's causing the problem? What do you mean by "your code blowing up"? Can't it be some other function treating the variables according to their old type?

Comment: @ Andras Deak, explicit typing is not forced in the code as the code is very old.

Comment: @ Andras Deak, it is a CFD code and by blowing up I mean it diverges exactly at iteration 1490, when I change the common block in all four subroutines from A to B, otherwise (using A) works fine.
You are right, it might be the case that some function is not aware of the new type, but at least I didn't find such a function.

Comment: Could you please fix the syntax errors in your example code.

Comment: @IanH, sorry for that, however there is not an "," in the original code, it just happened in writing the question.

Answer (score 1):

Common blocks establish storage association (Fortran 2008 Cl 16.5.3) between variables in different scoping units.  Nonpointer arrays in a storage association context will "occupy a sequence of contiguous storage sequences, one for each array element, in array element order".

What you are doing with a common block like:

```
      COMMON/MYBK/
     & C0(I,J,K),C1(I,J,K),C2(I,J,K),
     & C3(I,J,K),C4(I,J,K),C5(I,J,K),
     & CD0(I,J,K),CD1(I,J,K),CD2(I,J,K),
     & CD3(I,J,K),CD4(I,J,K),CD5(I,J,K)
```

This will define a block of memory so that each of these arrays is laid out in contiguous storage sequences for each variable back-to-back.  The definition of the common block determines a single storage association shared by each scoping unit the block appears in.

If you change the types of any of these variables in one scoping unit, but not all of them, what occurs is a mismatch of which bytes in the storage association belong to which variables and what indexes they appear at.  For example if `C0` is a `real` in one scoping unit and a `double precision` in another scoping unit and storage associated via a common block then the first element of the array `C0(1)` declared as `double precision` in its scoping unit will occupy the same data as the first two element the `C0(1:2)` in the scoping unit it is declared as `real`.

If you want to update `C0`, `C1` and `C2` to be `double precision` you need not modify any of the common blocks, but you must make sure that the type, kind, and rank of `C0`, `C1`, and `C2` are the same in every scoping unit that references the common block.  If you do not, you will have a mismatch in the storage association and your program will not work.

Comment: many thanks for your reply.
I've made sure that the type, kind, and rank of C0, C1, and C2 are identical in all four subroutines. But, still my the solution diverges. 
Could it be because of the arithmetic expressions involving the elements of  C0, C1, and C2, as the other operands are in single precision?

Comment: @bloodybutunbowed0 its impossible to know just from what you've posted.

Comment: @ casey you are right, unfortunately the code has around 24 k lines and it is very hard to trace the variable evolutions and on top of that I am not allowed to post it. Anyway thank you so much!

Comment: @bloodybutunbowed0 it could also be related to implementations of maths functions. For instance, `sqrt` vs `dsqrt` and similar stuff.